# eclipse Android Xml file design view

Tags: android, eclipse, android-xml

my Android xml fle Design look like this. [image]

but i want to view like this so how can do this?

[image]

Comment: do you have adt plugin installed? try updating it, is your project android project? also did you create a new android xml file or just general xml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on xml and select **`open with -> Android XML Resources Editor`** and also

you can try **`open with -> Android Layout Editor`** to have Design Layout tab.

Comment: Note that this does not work with XML files found under `res/xml` (e.g. Fragment layouts).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem earlier for all xml files but not for manifest file ,now it resolved 
in my application our requirement is When the orientation of the activity changes place the appropriate land folder and xml files.in that we give wrong naming conventions for the layout folders instead of layout-land,layout-land-hdpi,layout-land-mdpi,layout-land-ldpi,layout-port,layout-port-hdpi,layout-port-mdpi,layout-port-ldpi when ever we correct the naming conventions it comes normally.